how to install swapon in macOS with M1 chip
When I tried to install swapon in macOS 13.3.1 with M1 chip, shows error:
➜  bin git:(release-2.0.3) ✗ brew install swapon
==> Auto-updating Homebrew...
Adjust how often this is run with HOMEBREW_AUTO_UPDATE_SECS or disable with
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE. Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> New Formulae
kubelogin                                                                                            poutine

You have 24 outdated formulae and 3 outdated casks installed.

Warning: No available formula with the name "swapon". Did you mean waon or saxon?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
waon                                                                                                 saxon

To install waon, run:
  brew install waon

Am I missing something? is it possible to install swapon in macOS ?

Could you link to the source of this tool? I'm not sure why you're trying to find something from the brew tool rather than searching the repository on the web with https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ as there's nothing with swap that anyone has uploaded yet to the community repository. See the text Warning: No available formula with the name "swapon" That answers the first question of what you might be missing.

Swap usage in macOS and Linux is different don't expect Linux tools to work on macOS and vice versa. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

The message you get from Homebrew simply says that there is no Homebrew formula for swapon.
If somebody ported swapon from Linux to macOS, you should be able to compile it directly from source. But I'm not sure a port would even be possible or make sense. https://github.com/Leo-YiLuan/Disable-Swap-Memory-macOS14 might give some pointers on how to manage swap on macOS (disabling swap may crash your system though).
